# msdeploy rollback feature

Tags: .net, deployment, msbuild, continuous-integration, msdeploy

Am developing our deployment to different environment using MSDeploy technology. Just want to know how can we rollback particular deployment on ERROR in the batch file itself. Are there any builtin command?

One way can be to package the current site at a particular location and then deploy that package on any error in batch file. But don't want to follow that step and looking for any alternative that MSDeploy provides

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, perhaps there is more going on here than you have stated, but in the simplest case if you build a deployment package using visual studio the batch file it generates has a command line switch to do a "whatif" deployment.  You just execute the batch with a "/t" and it will simulate a deployment and report back any errors (without actually deploying of course).  There is some variance in how msdeploy is setup so maybe you could post more detail into exactly what you are doing?